What is the correct way to guarantee memory order consistency when using an ISR on an ESP8266
I'm writing code for an ESP8266 microcontroller that makes use of an ISR to perform actions at a very specific frequency.  I have the ISR working correctly, and performing the necessary actions, that's not the problem.
The ISR relies on four uint32_t values to do what it needs to, and to maintain correct behavior they must be updated as a single block of four.  Having the non-ISR mainline code update only two, then having the ISR pre-empt the mainline, do its work and return, and then have the mainline finish updating the other two will lead to errors that are not acceptable.
So I've got the following nine values:
uint32_t activeData1;
uint32_t activeData2;
uint32_t activeData3;
uint32_t activeData4;

uint32_t newData1;
uint32_t newData2;
uint32_t newData3;
uint32_t newData4;
bool newDataAvailable = false;

My ISR is coded as follows:
// IRAM_ATTR is a necessary attribute for ISRs on the
// ESP8266, without it they may not work correctly.
void IRAM_ATTR TimerISR()
{
    // Do stuff with activeData[1-4]
    if (newDataAvailable)
    {
        activeData1 = newData1;
        activeData2 = newData2;
        activeData3 = newData3;
        activeData4 = newData4;
        newDataAvailable = false;
    }
{

According to the "tribal knowledge" in the Arduino community, I should be using volatile as a qualifier for newData[1-4] and newDataAvailable.
However everything I read here on SO, e.g. the first answer to this question:
How do I Understand Read Memory Barriers and Volatile
seems to indicate that volatile is not the correct solution, I should be using
std::atomic<bool> newDataAvailable;

as the declaration, then using the following to set it true:
    newDataAvailable.store(true, memory_order_release);

and the following to test it in the ISR:
    if (newDataAvailable.load(memory_order_acquire))

Is this sufficient, or do I need to add or change anything else to get a 100% guarantee of the desired behavior?
-- Edit --
To clarify what's at least partly responsible for the confusion, I'm not crystal clear whether this counts as a multi-threading problem or not.  The "mainline" code is a single thread, and the ISR behaves a little like an asynchronous function call, because I do have the guarantee that they run on the same core: the ESP8266 is a single core CPU so that's kinda a given.  It's just that I have no control over precisely when the ISR gets invoked.

volatile is probably good enough for a simple case like this with a single thread and an interrupt. You might want to disable interrupts during your "critical section" in the main code.

@pmacfarlane ``You might want to disable interrupts during your "critical section" in the main code''  That's a very interesting idea that simply hadn't occurred to me.  I can still "double buffer" them since generation takes a number of slower operations, but then just disable interrupts for the four copies into the active values.
